# Apache Lucene: How to read segment/Index files from a jar

Tags: apache, jar, lucene

how will I read Segment/index  files which is stored inside a jar file using Apache Lucene. If files are kept in a folder then it works properly.But I have to read the file from a jar only.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality out of the box. To make this happen, you would need to implement `o.a.l.store.Directory` and feed it to the `IndexReader`.

Needless to say, performance for such a thing would suffer as effectively every change would have to be zipped/unzipped.